# gmapping with multiple lidars

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar, octomap, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

we have used a single lidar with slam-gmapping but now we want to extend this with multiple lidars (around 4 sick lidars).
is there anyway to maybe merge the data together and continue using slam-gmapping (as ive read AMCL can subscribe to two LaserScan topics and combine it into one topic but would this be feasible).

otherwise is it advisable to have a gmapping node for each lidar and then combine the costmap created

Or alternatively use octomap to input all the data to one map and create a cost map

what would be the best approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261259/gmapping-with-multiple-lidars/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [cob_scan_unifier](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_driver/tree/indigo_dev/cob_scan_unifier) for this. I am using for with two 270° scanners.

[Here](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_robots/blob/indigo_dev/cob_bringup/drivers/scan_unifier.launch) is example launch file.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0